# GWT: SafeHtmlRenderer

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to resolve a deprecation warning ***The constructor TextInputCell(SafeHtmlRenderer) is deprecated*** raised in the latest version of GWT (2.6):

```
Column<InterimReport, String> contextColumn = new Column<InterimReport, String>(
        new TextInputCell(new SafeHtmlRenderer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void render(String result, SafeHtmlBuilder builder) {
                builder.appendHtmlConstant(result);
            }

            @Override
            public SafeHtml render(String result) {
                return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(result);
            }
        }
        )
        )
    {

    @Override
    public String getValue(InterimReport ir) {
        return ir.get("context");
    }
};
```

The TextInputCell holds a URL (see `String result`) to some page on the internet. I don't know what to use in its place. I found [this HyperlinkCell class](https://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/listwidget/client/ui/HyperlinkCell.java?r=12) but can't work out whether:

1. this is a good approach (should I be doing something with `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Anchor` instead?)
   or
2. if it's the right approach, how to actually implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current `SafeHtmlRenderer`, which works around a [previous bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5993) of `TextInputCell`'s default behavior, you can just switch to the default constructor: `new TextInputCell()`.